# Saving an image in Chrome in one step

Tags: google-chrome, browser, images, workflow

I am a Designer. I save hundreds of images a day to share with coworkers and for personal research.

All the browsers I use beside from Chrome have a right-click option called `Save Image to Downloads`. The user right-clicks, selects "Save image to downloads" and - done.

In Chrome however, one needs to go through a cumbersome process of clicking Save Image As... . Which then opens a pop-up window (which can take time depending on the size of the folder this defaults to), and then you have to click on Save. Two more steps, multiplied by the number of times someone needs to do this.

There used to be a really good Add-on, [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-image-to-downloads/enjefpkmlibebgbbgidmhpmjhcdffhfm?hl=en), which absolutely doesn't work anymore.

And I'm honestly out of options to solve this problem. Yes, I do use other browsers sometimes, but I have one account I use Chrome for a lot, so I'd really like to be able to do this in Chrome.

### Can someone save an image in one step using Chrome?

Comment: Have a look at the DownThemAll extension https://www.downthemall.net/

Comment: Is it secure? It says upon install "It can: Read and change all your data on the websites you visit; Read and change your browsing history; Display notifications; Manage your downloads; Open downloaded files". I get why the 3 last ones are there but the first ones? Google just removed a lot of extensions that were actually malware...

Comment: @MicroMachine Anecdotal, but I have personally used DownThemAll for years and never had any issues with bad behavior. It's genuinely one extension I would recommend without hesitation.

Answer (score 2):

1st You should go to chrome settings-> advanced settings and Uncheck '**Ask where to save each file before downloading**' if you haven't done so already"

After that

[image]

1.You can use this extension its from github and works good

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/im-a-gentleman/afjaicccalbbickikgdegaihmajaidpd

**Or**

2.Click on the image and just press Ctrl + S to save it.

Comment: 'Ask where to save each file before downloading' is already urned off. Your second option (click the image and do CTRL+S) doesn't work. I am assuming you are saying to leave the mouse button clicked while doing so, which is not a "simple" solution either (releasing mouse button would take the user to the page). I tried the extension you linked but could not make it work. I am looking for a simple process the way other browsers do it.

Comment: clicking on image pressing ctrl+s clearly works but it should be image url not webpage I will look for better solution